# Does the PHP script run after user pressing ctrl +c on user input?

Tags: php, shell, deployment

I have a php schell script which at some point calls:

```
$input = @trim(@fgets(STDIN));
```

Now my question is, just to make sure, Is it 100% true that the script will stop when i hit the **CTRL + C** command there? Or will the script continue to run and  I have to handle it appropriately?

Comment: `PHP` is server `side scripting language` . it has nothing to with the user activity on client side directly.

Comment: @sgt you didn't get the scenario correctly. They are calling that from Shell, not via a browser. A web browser has nothing to do with `ctrl + c` in that context

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Don't supress your code like that in production. Handle it properly

Comment: Well, i tried and the funny thing is, it seems ctrl + c dous stop the execution. i tried a fwrite after it and nothing happens when i go ctrl+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Update

I checked. and it dous stop the execution of the ctrl + c. You have specually to config the php to ignore user interuption commands. :D